# Creating a SUMIFS with multiple conditions

Tags: excel

Basically, i have a page on my spreadsheet giving a summary of total payments, and another with a summary of total expenses, as well as a seperate page for individual transactions.

I now need to do a `SUMIFS` to calculate total expenses for a period by using the current sumifs, and adding another condition, only to add corresponding values to the dates when the item is also classified as an expense.

Current formula:

```
=IF(SUMIFS('Cash Payments'!$F$4:$F$216,'Cash Payments'!$E$4:$E$216,">="&DATE(D$3,7,1),'Cash Payments'!$E$4:$E$216,"<="&DATE(D$3,7,31))=0,"n/a",SUMIFS('Cash Payments'!$F$4:$F$216,'Cash Payments'!$E$4:$E$216,">="&DATE(D$3,7,1),'Cash Payments'!$E$4:$E$216,"<="&DATE(D$3,7,31)))
```

- expense column is 'Cash Payments'!$C$4:$C$216

I only need help with June 2018, as i can simply adjust each following month.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your formula just needs the inclusion of `'Cash Payments'!$C$4:$C$216` in **criteria_range3** and `"Expenses"` as **criteria3**:

```
=IF(SUMIFS('Cash Payments'!$F$4:$F$216,'Cash Payments'!$E$4:$E$216,">="&DATE(D$3,7,1),'Cash Payments'!$E$4:$E$216,"<="&DATE(D$3,7,31),'Cash Payments'!$C$4:$C$216,"Expenses")=0,"n/a",SUMIFS('Cash Payments'!$F$4:$F$216,'Cash Payments'!$E$4:$E$216,">="&DATE(D$3,7,1),'Cash Payments'!$E$4:$E$216,"<="&DATE(D$3,7,31),'Cash Payments'!$C$4:$C$216,"Expenses"))
```

It may be better to rewrite your formula though:

```
=SUMIFS('Cash Payments'!$F$4:$F$216,'Cash Payments'!$E$4:$E$216,">="&DATE(D$3,7,1),'Cash Payments'!$E$4:$E$216,"<="&DATE(D$3,7,31),'Cash Payments'!$C$4:$C$216,"Expenses")
```

This is just the formula without the check for 0 balance.  You can display the n/a using custom number formatting:

```
£#,##0.00;[Red]-£#,##0.00;"n/a"
```

This will display £15.30 or -£15.30 (in red) or 'n/a'.  The value stored in the cell will be 0, but 'n/a' will be displayed.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68